# How to split up an array of 3D models

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation

To make a game, I downloaded an asset that was a 3D voxel model with multiple variations. You are supposed to switch between them to make a sort of animation. However, since they are all one object and mesh, I don't know how to detach them. They are arranged in a sprite-sheet-like manner. However, I don't know how to separate them in Unity3D. Is this possible?

I tried messing with the mesh, but that did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I do not know how to do this within Unity. It may be possible with a custom script. However, a simple solution would be to use Blender:

For example:
[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z66ha.png) I have 3 cubes as 1 model.

1. Press "tab" to go into edit mode
2. Press "a" to select all vertices
3. Press "p" to bring up the [separate menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zc2tP.png)
4. Click "By Loose Parts"

I now have [3 different objects](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c6LHI.png).

You can export these objects back into Unity.

This will work so long as the different "frames" of your 3D spritesheet have some space between them.